# Convert data frame of values into binary data frame where each unique value is a column

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, data-extraction

I'm reading in data from a csv file where each row contains some number of individual strings:

e.g.

```
data.csv ->
    x,f,t,h,b,g
    d,g,h
    g,h,a,s,d
    f
    q,w,e,r,t,y,u,i,o

data <- read.csv("data.csv", header = FALSE)
```

I want to transform this input into a data frame where the columns are the set of unique strings present in the input. In this case, the columns would be the set of strings `{x,f,t,h,b,g,d,a,s,q,w,e,r,y,u,i,o}`. Additionally, the new data frame should contain a row for each row in the input data frame such that a column will have the value `1` if the column's name was present in that row in the input data frame, or `0` if the column's name was not present in that input row.

In this example, the desired output would be the following:

```
    x f t h b g d a s q w e r y u i o
   ----------------------------------
1 | 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 | 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
3 | 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
4 | 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
5 | 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

The code below is what I currently have. However, the output `df` ends up being a data frame with what appear to be the correct columns, but 0 rows.

I'm very inexperienced at R, and this was my attempt at putting together something that works. It seems to work as expected up until the call to `apply()`, which unexpectedly doesn't add anything to `df`.

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv", header = FALSE)

columnNames = c()
for (row in data) {
  for (eventName in row) {
    if (!(eventName %in% columnNames)) {
      columnNames = c(columnNames, eventName)
    }
  }
}
columnNames = t(columnNames)

df = data.frame(columnNames)
colnames(df) = columnNames
df = df[-1,]

apply(data, 1, function(row, df) {
  dat = data.frame(columnNames)
  colnames(dat) = columnNames
  dat = dat[-1,]

  for (eventName in row) {
    if (eventName != "") {
      dat[1,eventName] = 1
    }
  }

  df = rbind(df, dat)
}, df)
```

After the script finishes it tells me there were many warnings of the following two forms:

```
9: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = 1) : invalid factor level, NA generated
10: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = 1) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the dataset.  It is confusing from your input.

Comment: I'm just showing that the input is a standard, comma-separated csv file which gets converted by `read.csv`

Comment: Okay, anyway I updated the post if all of these are single character strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `mtabulate` after `split`ting the column by `,`

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(strsplit(as.character(df1[,1]), ","))
```

---

Or with `base R` methods by `split`ting the column  by `,`, set the names of the `list` output as the sequence of rows, convert the `list` to `data.frame` (`stack`), change the 'values' column to `factor` with `levels` specified and then get the frequency with `table`.

```
table(transform(stack(setNames(strsplit(as.character(df1[,1]), ","), 1:nrow(df1)))[2:1], 
           values = factor(values, levels = unique(values))))
# 
#    x f t h b g d a s q w e r y u i o
#  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#  2 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#  3 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#  4 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#  5 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

#### Update

If this is not a single column,

```
mtabulate(apply(df2, 1, FUN = function(x) x[x!=""]))
```

Or

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(transform(stack(setNames(apply(df2, 1, 
     FUN = function(x) x[x!=""]), 
           1:nrow(df2)))[2:1],  values = factor(values, levels = unique(values)))))
#    
#    x f t h b g d a s q w e r y u i o
#  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#  2 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#  3 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#  4 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#  5 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("x,f,t,h,b,g", "d,g,h", "g,h,a,s,d", "f", 
"q,w,e,r,t,y,u,i,o")), .Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df2 <- structure(list(v1 = c("x", "d", "g", "f", "q"), v2 = c("f", "g", 
"h", "", "w"), v3 = c("t", "h", "a", "", "e"), v4 = c("h", "", 
"s", "", "r"), v5 = c("b", "", "d", "", "t"), v6 = c("g", "", 
"", "", "y"), v7 = c("", "", "", "", "u"), v8 = c("", "", "", 
"", "i"), v9 = c("", "", "", "", "o")), .Names = c("v1", "v2", 
"v3", "v4", "v5", "v6", "v7", "v8", "v9"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @fvgs Here I am assuming that you have a single column that have these strings.

Comment: Where are you assuming a single column? The data being read in is from a csv of the form described above. Neither the input nor the output are single columns. I'm trying out your example, but the output (using `View`) is very different from the desired data frame

Comment: @fvgs Okay, if it is not a single column, you must be having blanks in other columns, right as the number of elements in each row is different and I haven't seen you using `fill=TRUE` in read.csv`

Comment: I tried to address the blank issue by checking if `eventName != ""` in the last for loop. But using `fill=TRUE` seems like a much cleaner solution

Comment: I'm trying your updated solution using `table`, but the output produced when I look at it using `View` has the columns `ind`, `values`, and `freq`. There are other pieces of this codebase that expect the input to be exactly in the format described. I'm very new to R, but this doesn't seem to match the desired format. I suppose that may be because we're outputting a table rather than a data frame?

Comment: @fvgs You can convert it to `data.frame` with `as.data.frame.matrix(..` Updated the post.  It is giving the exact output you showed.

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks for all your help! Now I just need to understand exactly what each transformation is doing...